# get id from category name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm working on my application and i need to get the id for a specific category. for instance if the category is japanese it would give me an id of 2. i'm using sqlalchemy in python here is how i have my connection set up

```
url = f"postgresql://postgres:postgres@{dbendpoint}:5432/postgres"
engine_db = create_engine(url)
```

and this is how im setting up the pandas dataframe before sending it to postgres

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = name
df['address'] = addy
df['categoryID'] = null
```

where it says null is where i will plan to execute the query to grab the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the categories in a database table

```
"category"

category_id  category_name
-----------  -------------
          1  Canadian    
          2  Japanese    
          3  Australian
```

you can pull that into a DataFrame and then convert the contents to a dict:

```py
category_df = pd.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM category", engine
)
category_dict = {
    row.category_name: row.category_id
    for row in category_df.itertuples(index=False)
}
print(category_dict)
# {'Canadian': 1, 'Japanese': 2, 'Australian': 3}

print(category_dict["Japanese"])  # 2
```